# Where do "My site" and "My profiles" links come from?

Tags: navigation, custom-actions

Under the personal action menu, there are two links :

- My site
- My profile

I'm trying to understand how they are generated and by which component/feature. However the highest container in the control hierarchy I was able to discover is the `FeatureMenuTemplate` control, within `PersonalActions` control (itself in the welcome.ascx control).

If I replace the Welcome.ascx by a custom one with this minimal content :

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.Welcome,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"   AutoEventWireup="false" compilationMode="Always" %>
  <SharePoint:PersonalActions  accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,personalactions_menu_ak%>" ToolTip="<%$Resources:wss,open_menu%>" runat="server" id="ExplicitLogout" Visible="false">
    <CustomTemplate>
     <SharePoint:FeatureMenuTemplate runat="server"
         FeatureScope="None"
         Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
         GroupId="PersonalActions"
         id="ID_PersonalActionMenu"
         UseShortId="true" 
         >
       <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="ID_LoginAsDifferentUser"
                 Text="<%$Resources:wss,personalactions_loginasdifferentuser%>"
                 Description="<%$Resources:wss,personalactions_loginasdifferentuserdescription%>"
                 MenuGroupId="200"
                 Sequence="100"
                 UseShortId="true"
                 />

     </SharePoint:FeatureMenuTemplate>
    </CustomTemplate>
</SharePoint:PersonalActions>
<SharePoint:ApplicationPageLink runat="server" id="ExplicitLogin"
    ApplicationPageFileName="Authenticate.aspx" AppendCurrentPageUrl="true"
    Text="<%$Resources:wss,login_pagetitle%>" style="display:none" Visible="false" />
```

This works, but there are still the two links mentionned before.

I tried to dive with reflector to understand how these links are generated. I tried to find any custom action. No success.

What is causing this two links to appear ?

PS: my actual goal is to remve this links, I found some workaround on the web but I'm still looking for an explanation, for my personal comprehension (and sanity)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found how all the things is working.

First, there is a server control `SocialNavigationControl`. This control is rendered within `SocialData.ascx`.

There is also a delegate control override in `SocialDelegateControl.xml` file of `SocialRibbonControl` feature. This override applies to `GlobalSiteLink2` delegate control.

Finally, the `v4.master` page references this control using a standard `<SharePoint:DelegateControl ControlId="GlobalSiteLink2" ID="GlobalDelegate2" Scope="Farm" runat="server" />` declaration.

I was looking in the wrong control. This is not the `Welcome.ascx` that populates the links, but another control which is adding controls when rendering using (I guess) Ribbons's JS api.

Comment: Awesome!!! Don't forget the farm feature you can simply enable/disable

Answer (score 1):

If you donot need the MySite and MyProfile... Then you can disable the feature as follows

1.Central Administration>Manage Service Applications>User Profile Service Application>People>Manage User Permissions>Select All Authenticated Users>**Uncheck** **Use Personal Features** >Click Ok

2.Central Administration>Manage Services on server>**Stop** **User Profile Service**

Comment: this is one of the workaround I mentioned. As I said, I don't want to remove them, but I want to understand how they are added to the menu.

Comment: They are custom actions in feature.xml... You can also add custom actions in that location.

Comment: I know. But in this case, it's not custom actions