# Hide "My Site" Top Link Bar Item in MySite

Tags: my-site, navigation, top-link-bar, personalization

In SharePoint 2010, the top-left link is "My Site". How can I hide or customize this link to allow me to put in my own link in the very top-left?

I know I can use Personalization Site Links to add an item to the end, or edit the Top Link Bar in the MySite to add a link as the second link, but I'd like to edit the very first link (without resorting to Master Page changes etc).

My current solution is to add a Content Editor and paste in the following CSS, but I'd welcome other suggestions:

```
<style type="text/css">
DIV.ms-globalnavicon {
    DISPLAY: none
}
</style>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I found that Erik here suggests to just add the solution I used to your custom CSS, but because there's no "Master Page" menu option in MySite (no publishing model), I had to use PowerShell to set the 

http://erikswenson.blogspot.com.au/2010/12/hide-sp2010-my-site-link-in-top.html

Answer (score 1):

I hope you will get different way to do achieve this by following url:

[How to hide/show My Site link on portal in personal menu?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34778/how-to-hide-show-my-site-link-on-portal-in-personal-menu)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a Content Editor to hard-code the CSS onto each MySite page, you can use a custom CSS styles-sheet and then simply set the AlternateCssUrl on the Web Site with PowerShell:

**CSS (custom.css):**

```
/* Hide "My Site" link top-left 
    http://erikswenson.blogspot.com.au/2010/12/hide-sp2010-my-site-link-in-top.html 
*/
DIV.ms-globalnavicon {
    DISPLAY: none
}
```

**PowerShell:**

```
$w.AlternateCssUrl = "/Style%20Library/Custom.css"
$w.Update()
```

The "My Site" top-left link is now hidden and you can use Site Settings/Top Link Bar to arrange your links how you like (e.g. I make my Portal link the first link and My Site the second link).